# Is it possible to make a mathematica program which can be viewed online by anyone?

Tags: mathematica-online

When I first learned about [Mathematica online](https://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/online/), I was very excited about it. However, it is not a free service, but a subscription similar to normal mathematica. Moreover, everything I look up about MO is like announcements of its existence and similar, blog style stuff, but where the hell is it? How do I (as a mathematica subscriber) access it? And especially, can I make programs in it that the public can view without a subscription?

As a MWE, let's just go with this. How can I make the following visualization appear at a webpage for which I can simply share the URL and a public user can see it and manipulate the slider?

```
Manipulate[Plot[Sin[x (1 + a x)], {x, 0, 6}], {a, 0, 2}]
```

Comment: https://www.wolfram.com/cdf-player/ might be what you seek.

Comment: That is pretty similar to my goal, yes. However, the solution is not what I desire, because it requires a user to install something just to view it. In fact, I can't even test this out at the moment without administrator privileges on my work pc. I'm hoping there's a better solution available, but it's looking like Wolfram wants to protect itself to the point of limitation.

Comment: I don't think Wolfram offers a tool that converts "Manipulate" to HTML5, Javascript, or anything like that. It would be interesting and theoretically possible to create one.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EjCWdsrVcBM at 35 minutes into the video Wolfram demonstrates a cloud object

Answer (score 2):

```
CloudDeploy[Manipulate[Plot[Sin[x (1 + a x)], {x, 0, 6}], {a, 0, 2}],Permissions -> "Public"]
```

Here is what I found in the documentation:
Best of luck:

http://wolfram.com/xid/05fd5yprh6-xcjygt

[image]

Comment: You must add the option `Permissions -> "Public"` if you want that anybody can use it. But it will spend "Cloudcredits", I think

Comment: This asks me to sign in with my Wolfram ID and password.  I guess "public" would need to have a Wolfram ID to access this manipulate object?

Comment: @drN No, normally, "Public" can access the manipulate object without Wolfram ID, without registration, even without free registration. For the user, there is absolutly nothing to do. Though the one who create the object must be registred and have some CloudCredits available. Some CloudCredit are offered by Wolfram (Personnaly, I have obtained freely 6250 CloudCredit without cost, and I think I will have 1000 CloudCredits/Month automaticcaly, freely)

Comment: How can I check if I currently have CloudCredits or if I am on a Mathematica subscription that comes with an automatic CloudCredit income rate?